# UTL_HTTP Begin Request failure after Database upgrade

Tags: oracle, http, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am currently running into issues

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29259: end-of-input reached
```

when trying to do the begin_request method:

```
utl_http.set_wallet('','');
v_soap_ep = WALLET_PATH;
utl_http.begin_request(v_soap_ep, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
```

This issue just started occurring today (Worked yesterday), and no changes to the code happened, although there was a database upgrade from 11g -> 12c.  The WALLET_PATH links to a valid address, but the WALLET_PATH links to a 11g database (not 12c).  I have little knowledge on this subject, and was wondering if this error was possibly caused by the two different database versions trying to work together.

Note:  I put an invalid address into the c_soap_ep variable, and recieved a different error. (So that is why I am thinking there might be a compatability issue).  Any thoughts or areas I can check out would be helpful, thanks.

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

Comment: The information (i.e. code) you provide is a bit low. Please provide the full procedure.

Comment: I don't think more code will provide better overview, but I may be wrong. The basic issue is with utl_http making/beginning a request.  What benefit do you think including the whole procedure provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use 11g wallets in 12c. Because, wallet creation is totally different in 12c as it uses new syntax.

For [example](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ASOAG/asotrans_config.htm#ASOAG10282):

```
-- Create
ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT CREATE KEYSTORE 'keystore_location' 
IDENTIFIED BY software_keystore_password;
-- Open
ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE OPEN 
IDENTIFIED BY software_keystore_password;
-- Close
ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE CLOSE 
IDENTIFIED BY   software_keystore_password;
```

So, try creating a new wallet/keystore in 12c then use it for `utl_http`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot create a new wallet/keystore, I was hitting the existing one. Our DBA is now looking into this, I'll post/mark this as the fix once they respond